# Is a switched neutral light fixture up to code in canada?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, neutral

In Canada, is it legal to have a single pole switch turn off a light by switching the neutral wire only?

I'm pretty sure it's not to code, but my brother in law is adamant his way is okay. I'd like to be able to cite the Canadian electrical code.

Comment: The switch is only effective in turning off the light. The hot is still energized so it'll still kill you. Tell him that this is negligence. Any harm or death that results will be on his head.

Comment: Is it a white wire on each screw or does one screw have a black wire?  White on each is bad, a black and white is an old style switch loop and good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Canadian Electrical Code 14-016 "Devices required by this Section shall not be connected in any grounded conductors."

Comment: Grounded conductor is another name for neutral, which most people do not know.